# Catch error and put inside a component ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I have an issue, this issue is to take an error from my try catch and pass this message error to my custom alert component.

Below is my code:

```
 export const Register = () => { 
   const dispatch = useDispatch(); 
   
   const [openError, setOpenError] = useState(false);

   const AlertError = openError ? (
    <Dialog open={openError}>
      <AlertCard
        open={openError}
        handleClose={handleCloseError}
        borderTop="1vh solid red"
        color="black"
        severity="error"
        title="Cadastro falhou"
        description='message' //put here message error
      />
    </Dialog>
  ) : (
    ""
  );

 const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      first_name: "",
      last_name: "",
      confirmPassword: "",
      newsletter: "",
    },
    validationSchema: validationSchema,
    onSubmit: async (values) => {
      setIsLoading(true)
      dispatch(signupUserPending());
      dispatch(requestConfirmEmailPending());
      try {
        if (document.getElementById("checkbox").checked) {
          values.newsletter = "on";
        }
        const singUpRes = await signup(values);
        dispatch(signupUserSuccess(singUpRes));
        dispatch(getUserSuccess(singUpRes));
        dispatch(getTokenSuccess(singUpRes));

        const confirmEmailRes = await requestConfirmEmail(singUpRes.user.email);
        dispatch(requestConfirmEmailSuccess(confirmEmailRes));
        setOpenSuccess(true);
        navigate("/confirm-token");

      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message); //need take this message error
        dispatch(signupUserFailure(err));
        dispatch(requestConfirmEmailFailure(err));
        setIsLoading(false);
        setOpenError(true);
      }
    },
  });

  return ({AlertError}...rest of code)
}
```

I need to catch a message error which come from the backend, and put this error inside my props description on my custom alert error. But I don't know how to make this. I tried make this for some hours but could not achieve success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, whenever you want to mutate local values to be rendered in a component, you would be updating the React state.

See, you are already using the `useState` hook for controlling whether the `AlertError` is showing or not with `[openError, setOpenError]`, you should just need to do the same with the error message.

Additionally, you might want to use the error message itself to control the render of the Alert.

Here is a snippet of what I mean:

```js
export const Register = () => {
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const formik = useFormik({
    onSubmit: async (values) => {
      try {
        await signup(values);
      } catch (err) {
        setErrorMessage(err.message);
      }
    },
  });
  return <AlertError open={!!errorMessage} description={errorMessage} />;
};

const AlertError = ({ open, description, ...rest }) => (
  <Dialog open={open}>
    <AlertCard open={open} description={description} {...rest} />
  </Dialog>
);
```

Comment: Hi Felipe thanks a lot for your explanation about this case, this help me a lot to solve my issue!